# WP8 led light running under screenlock

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In such applications like Flashlight-X, Flashlight-XT there is a feature implemented: running led light under screen lock.
General implementation of enabling light:

```
var captureDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back).First());

captureDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode, VideoTorchMode.On);
```

This code starts the light but the light gets disabled after 20 sec after screen gets locked.
What should be done to keep light alive under the lock?

Blocking UI thread on obscured event works but do not want to keep it blocked after unlocking device.

Some people suggest to disable UserIdleDetectionMode, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would allow your app to run under lockscreen:

```
    void rootFrame_Unobscured(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        status.Text = "coming back from lock screen!";
        // resume the application
    }

    void rootFrame_Obscured(object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
    {

        status.Text = "going under lock screen!";
        //minimize CPU usage, and  save the settings.
    }

    private void RunAppUnderLockscreen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The application will run under lock screen");
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
        PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        if (rootFrame != null)
        {
            rootFrame.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(rootFrame_Obscured);
            rootFrame.Unobscured += new EventHandler(rootFrame_Unobscured);
        }
    }
```

Have a look at [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx) to get more helpful information, like:

> Please keep in mind that f your application sets
>   `ApplicationDetectionMode` to `IdleDetectionMode.Disabled`, it can not
>   change that back to `IdleDetecionMode.Enabled` until application is
>   either launched again (so a full restart) or deactivated and then
>   reactivated.